# Split string by delimiter and transpose value(s) vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel separated by commas (,)

```
       column  
cell1:  1,2,3
cell2:   2,4
```

I want to split each cell so that values appear in vertical cell so that each is converted to

```
cell1 => split into 3 vertical cells containing values 1,2,3 
cell2 => split into 2 vertical cells containing values 2,4
```

I  found many ways to do this horizontally, but struggling splitting over vertical cells.

Comment: `Data -> Text to Columns` delimited by comma, and then `copy paste special` the result and `transpose`

Answer (score 1):

Starting with data like:

[image]

First select the data you wish to process and run this macro:

```
Sub Vertical()
    Dim i As Long, st As String
    i = 1
    Dim startP As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If i = 1 Then
            st = r.Text
            i = 2
        Else
            st = st & "," & r.Text
        End If
    Next r

    Set startP = Selection(1, 2)
    ary = Split(st, ",")
    i = 1
    For Each a In ary
        startP(i, 1).Value = a
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

To produce:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To convert each cell from a horizontally displayed comma separated list into a vertically spaced comma separated list, run this macro:

```
Sub Vertical2()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Replace(r.Value, ",", "," & vbCrLf)
        r.WrapText = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

on the selected cells:

[image]

Comment: HEY WHAT I WANTED IS FIRST CELL DIVIDED VERTICALLY TO 1,2,3 , SECOND VERTICALLY IN CELL TO 4,5 AND 3RD HAVE 4 CELLS INSIDE VERTICALLY CONTAINING A,B,C,D, AS PER YOUR EXAMPLE

Comment: Do you the **1,2,3** in a single cell, but vertical rather than horizontal??

Comment: Yes exactly , this is what I wants to achieve, Each cell split vertically into cell according to delimiter,

Comment: Its helpful but what I wanted is to split this cell into 3 cells (Vertical)

Answer (score -1):

See the following link for a utility in Excel.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7